# building a new linked list odd from the original linked lists x 's odd positions in java

Tags: java, linked-list

So for example if the original list `x` was `3 5 6 8 9 2`, the new linked list `h` would be `3 6 9`

So I thought my method was working and being awesome but when the original list had more than 3 elements, my list odd doesn't seem to be linked to the next node when list odd has more than 3 elements.

I believe the problem is in my for loop when the condition of my odd List isn't empty. 
So if u guys can let me know what I need to do i would appreciate it a lot! 
Since I'm new here it wont let me just add a print screen of my method so here is the best next thing :

```
public static Node oddPosition( iNode x){
    int count = 1;
    iNode oddList = null;
    for(Node temp = h; temp != null; temp = temp.next){
        if(count % 2 != 0 ){//<-----declares whether the position is odd or not
            //if oddList is empty
            if(oddList == null){
                oddList = new Node(temp.item);
                oddList.next = null;
            } 
            //if oddList is not empty
            oddList.next = new Node(temp.item);//<----here is where I believe the problem is for some reason my linked list isnt linking together
            oddList.next.next = null;
        }
        count++;
    }
    System.out.print("Odd list : ");
    print(oddList);
    return oddList;
}
```

Output :

```
Original list : 3 5 6 8 9 2
What is should display : 3 6 9
What I am getting : 3 9
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: im sorry it would have been so much easier if i could just display a pic of the output but thank u Ill add more to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep adding new elements to `oddList.next`. ou never change value of `oddList` so this way your result has only the first element and the last element. Somewhere you have to assign `oddList = oddList.next` to be able to add new values to the end of your list. And you probably also want to keep the first node in a separate value, for example `startOfList`.

So the result could be something like this:

```
public static Node oddPosition( iNode x){
int count = 1;
iNode oddList = null;
iNode startOfList = null;
 for(Node temp = h; temp != null; temp = temp.next){
    if(count % 2 != 0 ){//<-----declares whether the position is odd or not
        //if oddList is empty
        if(oddList == null){
            oddList = new Node(temp.item);
            startOfList = oddList;
            oddList.next = null;
        } 
        //if oddList is not empty
        oddList.next = new Node(temp.item);
        oddList.next.next = null;
        oddList = oddList.next;
      }
    count++;
    }
  System.out.print("Odd list : ");
  print(startOfList);
  return startOfList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ghaxx I knew that was the problem I just stuck on what to do! ur a life saver!;D